# cannot find py3_env.bat in OSGeo4W installation

Tags: osgeo4w

I am trying to install Trajectools in QGIS according to the following tutorial https://anitagraser.com/2019/02/02/movement-data-in-gis-20-trajectools-v1-released/ but I have the following problem, I can not find the file py3_env.bat in OSGeo4W installation

[image]

when I execute the sequence: OSGeo4W shell: call C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\py3_env.bat in the GDAL shell the following error appears:

[image]

Comment: Based on the title of the shell window, I'd say this is not the OSGeo4W shell. Also, did you install QGIS3 and corresponding Python3?

Answer (score 2):

This is because, you use qgis2 and py3_env.bat belongs to a Qgis3 installation.

Answer (score 2):

OSGeo4W now directly provides GeoPandas in the Libs section:

[image]

So there should be no need to install it manually anymore.